# Limit number of input types created using jquery append and keyup

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create an html element for every word which is being inputted into a text area. The code i have so far is:

```
<table id="sentencetable">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Enter Sentence</th>     <!-- colspan used to add text over multiple columns -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top">
      English :
    </td>
    <td>
      <textarea name="english" required></textarea>             <!-- inputs text areat in table data -->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top">
      Sanskrit :
    </td>
    <td>
      <textarea id="sanskrit" name="sanskrit" required></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <table id="add">

    </table>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sanskrit').keyup(function(){
        var sanskrit = this.value.trim();                     
        var x = sanskrit.split(' ');
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            $('#add').append('<input style="width:70px" placeholder="Enter Root" type="text" name="root'+i+'" required/>')
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

However for every key pressed it creates a new text field and I only want to create a new text field for every word inputted in the sanskrit textarea. Any ideas on how to do this.

Comment: "every word inputted" ... as in space-separated words? just listen for `e.which === 32`

Comment: You're only creating one text field for each word. But you're not removing the old ones every time you add new ones, so you'll get lots of text boxes.

Comment: Yes for every word a new text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sanskrit').keyup(function () {
        $.each(this.value.trim().split(/\s+/), function(i) {
            if ( ! $('[name="root'+i+'"]').length ) {

                var inp = $('<input />', {
                    css         : "width:70px",
                    placeholder : "Enter Root",
                    type        : "text",
                    name        : "root" + i,
                    required    : "required"
                });

                 $('#add').append(inp)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2uKvp/)

Comment: +1 For checking to see if the input already exists and +1 for using that method for creating inputs.

Comment: beat me doing the length check! i'll upvote since you had the forethought to include it with your original submission. :)

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the spacebar:

```
$('#sanskrit').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which === 32){
        var sanskrit = this.value.trim(),
            x = sanskrit.split(' '),
            $add = $('#add');

        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            if($add.find('input[name="root'+i+'"]').length === 0){
                $add.append('<input style="width:70px" placeholder="Enter Root" type="text" name="root'+i+'" required/>')
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Something like this will only perform the function only when you go to create a new word.

I edited this to only add new items if they do not already exist.

Comment: This will create multiple inputs with the same name. Is that the desired effect?